# Where is this class "HttpContext" exist in glassfish jersey 2.9?

Tags: jersey

Where is this class "`HttpContext`" exist in glassfish jersey `2.9` . I was using jersey `1.17.1` to use HttpContext where it was exist in package  `com.sun.jersey.api.core.HttpContext`.
But i did't find it in jersey 2.9.

Comment: It doesn't exist. What are you trying to do, and where are you trying to do it? Please post some code for help achieving your goal.

Comment: In my restful service using  Jersey 1 ,was using HttpContext to get the original request like httpcontext.getRequest().getEntity(String.class);  and also to get the content type, httpcontext.getRequest().getHeaderValue. Please suggest on this.

Comment: You don't need to do all that. To get the String, just have a String parameter (with no annotation). This will give you the body in String form. For the header just use `@HeaderParam("Content-Type") String type` as another parameter. This seems a bit odd that you are trying to do this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jersey 2.x had a lot of breaking changes, which partly caused by the fact that JAX-RS standard incorporated a lot of things in Jersey 1.x.

To quote https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/migration.html#mig-1.x

> This chapter is a migration guide for people switching from Jersey 1.x. Since many of the Jersey 1.x features became part of JAX-RS 2.0 standard which caused changes in the package names, we decided it is a good time to do a more significant incompatible refactoring, which will allow us to introduce some more interesting new features in the future. As the result, there are many incompatibilities between Jersey 1.x and Jersey 2.0. This chapter summarizes how to migrate the concepts found in Jersey 1.x to Jersey/JAX-RS 2.0 concepts.

The migration chapter does not indicate what happened to HttpContext, but it no longer exists in its old form.

Answer (score 3):

The direct replacement for `HttpContext` is not available in Jersey 2.x versions and unfortunately, this breaking change detail hasn't been mentioned anywhere in the [migration](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#mig-1.x) guide. Instead of searching for direct replacement, if we dig deeper into the interface `HttpContext`, based on the following method summary [image: method summary] [refer](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/1.19.1/jersey/index.html?com/sun/jersey/api/core/HttpContext.html)

we can infer that instead of using `HttpContext`, we can simply use the following out-of-the-box alternatives.

- Instead of `HttpContext#getRequest` use `@Context ContainerRequestContext crc`
- Instead of `HttpContext#getResponse` use `@Context ContainerResponseContext crc`
- Instead of `HttpContext#getUriInfo` use `@Context UriInfo uriInfo`
- Instead of `HttpContext#getProperties` use `ContainerRequestContext#getProperty`